# How to have create action on form instead of patch on show view Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Once a user create a record on my web app, he is redirected to the Home#show.

I would like to display the show view, but also add the partial of the create form view. How can I accomplish this?

What do I need to change to this form in order to force a "create" action on my show view?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@home, :html => { :class => "form-newsletter thirds" }) do |f| %>
                                                <%= f.error_notification %>
                                                <%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "Phone Number (5554440707)", label: false, input_html: { maxlength: 10, :style => 'height: 50px' }%>
                                                <%= f.input :sender_name, placeholder: "Your Name", label: false, input_html: { maxlength: 60, :style => 'height: 50px' } %>
                                                <div class="form-actions">
                                                    <%= f.submit "Place your Order", :type => :image, :src => image_path("checkout-logo-large.png") %>
                                                </div>
                                            <% end %>
```

Comment: If the record is already created, why would you want to show the create form?  Is this to allow the user to create another (different) record?

Comment: Yes, to allow a new record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening because you are passing `@home` to the form, which is already a saved record.

Change:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@home, ...
```

To:

```
<%= simple_form_for(Home.new, ...
```

This assumes that `Home.new` is how you instantiate a new (unsaved) model.  Alternatively, it may be simpler for you to just assign that to `@home` in your controller, and leave the form as is:

```
@home = Home.new
```